# What is the variable lifecycle before escape analysis?

Tags: go

First I apologize if this is an obvious or straight forward answer but I can't seem to wrap my head around the exact process under the hood for the following code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func xyz() *int {
    n := 42
    return &n
}

func main() {
    num := xyz()
    fmt.Println("The number is", *num)
}
```

My question is does the variable n get allocated to the stack before escape analysis and then once it's out of scope does it get garbage collected before getting allocated to the heap? How does Golang handle the pointer when the function xyz is returned? I'm asking for a bit of a technical step by step flow but also to clear up any knowledge gaps.

Comment: Escape analysis happens at compile time; allocation happens at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape analysis works at compile time. When the compiler realizes the address of variable `n` leaves the function, it compiles a function that looks like this:

```
func xyz() *int {
    n:=newInHeap(int)
    *n := 42
    return n
}
```

Here, `newInHeap` is a hypothetical function that always allocates the variable in heap. Regular `new` may allocate variables on the stack if the variable doesn't escape the function.

The lifetime of the returned pointer is controlled at runtime by regular GC rules.

Comment: oh wow, yeah that cleared it up for me. That makes sense that the compiler would use new().

Comment: Note that this is not necessarily exactly what it does, but the effect is the same.

Comment: The compiler does not use "new". It creates an intermediate assembly-like representation of the same logical concept.

Comment: Using `new` does not imply heap allocation, you can easily find `new(int) does not escape` in the escape analysis if it doesn't leave the stack.

Comment: @JimB, I edited the answer to reflect that.